# how can I delete the partly dowloaded app data

Tags: software-center

it might sound stupid, but I have a following problem:

right now I have very low storage on may laptop for some reasons, anyway, I wanted to install an application from ubuntu software centre, when I started downloaded only after a few seconds later I noticed that it was too big in size, I couldn't afford to loose so much space and I cancelled it, by the time I cancelled it had already downloaded around 200 MB and it occupied this amount of space on my hard drive. How can I get rid of it? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix. Nothing was installed on your computer, only the .deb file (or whatever Ubuntu uses, I never cared enough to actually pay attention) was downloaded into the cache folder that apt-get uses.

Type `sudo apt-get clean` then
          `sudo ap-get autoclean` and finally
         `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

The first command is probably the only one you really need but just as a matter of course I always run all three in order.

`apt-get clean` cleans out the local repository
`apt-get autoclean` clears out the local repository of retrieved package files
`apt-get autoremove` removes packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are no longer needed.

Comment: the answer fixes my problem indeed and thanks for that, but try to write clearly for the future.  I suggested a few formatting and review please